# jtable - accessing object behind the row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

using a jtable - 
Can I get the object behind the row

Comment: what do you mean with behind the row?

Comment: Well, I took the value in the column from the valueat. but now I want to get the object which I bounded. I used createJTableBining and binded it to a list

Comment: Actually one field in the table is a jcombobox and I want to create a listener to it. now, i need the object so I could change some other field value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data displayed in a JTable should be backed by a TableModel, in general a class mapping from a set of business objects to a "table-like" display.

Have a look at the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Answer (score 2):

If you tell us more about your usage scenario, one might come up with a good pattern...

As of now, @ChrisJ has the best tip.... YOu can return the POJO in one of the getValueAt columns...